# wordpress query post by a custom field that is post type

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields.

I have this query that gets all the post that have a custom field value for "artist" equal to the current page ID.

```
query_posts('meta_key=artist&meta_value='.$postID.'&post_type=page&order_by=title&order=DESC');
```

This works great as long as the custom field only has a number in it. I want to make my custom field a "post" . This isn't a problem because ACF has that option. But since the meta_value in my query will now need to get a value from an array I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: what is the type of the acf you are using to generate a field? post object or relationship?

Comment: so you need to query posts that have posts asociated with it?

Comment: Yes. I guess that's how you could say it. The custom field "artist" is a post object. So in the query I have I think I need to replace `meta_key=artist&meta_value='.$postID.'` with somthing like `meta_key=array(artist->ID)&meta_value='.$postID.'`

Answer (score 0):

Since the [Post Object](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/post-object/) field is used to generate the custom field, you don't need meta key/value for the query, you just need to check if the field exist.

So the query wold look something like this:

```
$all_pages = get_posts('post_type=page&order_by=title&order=DESC');
foreach($all_pages as $page) {
    if(get_field('artist', $page->ID)) { // here you check if field is populated
       // loop content
    }
}
```

Comment: that doest seem to work. One other note. The custom field allows multiple selection.